# Navigator: Callbacks get never triggered

Tags: flutter, here-api

I'm trying to integrate the HERE SDK for Flutter. I'm using Version 4.3.3.0.
I can display my location on the map, I'm also capable of updating the location while moving around but non of the `navigator` callbacks I registered gets triggered. This is the code for creating the `navigator`:

```
void _setupNavigation(NavigationData navigationData) {
  final RouteRepository routeRepository = RepositoryProvider.of<RouteRepository>(context);
  final NavigationBloc navigationBloc = BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc>(context);

  final here.LocationListener locationListener = _buildLocationListener();
  if (_simulate) {
    _locationSimulator = _buildLocationSimulator(
      navigationData: navigationData,
      locationListener: locationListener,
    );
  }

  _locationProvider = _buildLocationProvider(
    routeRepository: routeRepository,
    locationListener: locationListener,
  );

  _navigator = here.Navigator(_locationProvider);
  _navigator.routeDeviationListener =
      _buildRouteDeviationListener(navigationBloc: navigationBloc);
  _navigator.routeProgressListener =
      _buildRouteProgressListener(navigationBloc: navigationBloc);
  _navigator.navigableLocationListener =
      _buildNavigableLocationListener(navigationBloc: navigationBloc);
  _navigator.maneuverNotificationListener =
      _buildManeuverNotificationListener(navigationBloc: navigationBloc);
  _navigator.maneuverNotificationOptions =
      here.ManeuverNotificationOptions.withDefaults();
  _navigator.route = navigationData.routes?.mainRoute?.route;
  navigationBloc.add(StartNavigation(simulate: _simulate));
}
```

I create all the listeners according to the same pattern. Here is for example the `ManeuverListener`:

```
ManeuverNotificationListener _buildManeuverNotificationListener(
        {@required NavigationBloc navigationBloc}) =>
    here.ManeuverNotificationListener.fromLambdas(
      lambda_onManeuverNotification: (String maneuver) {
        _flutterTts.speak(maneuver);
        navigationBloc.add(NewManeuverNotification(maneuver));
      },
    );
```

Could please someone point me into the right direction? What is missing to make the callbacks get triggered?

**UPDATE**
This is how I build the LocationProvider:

```
LocationProvider _buildLocationProvider({
  @required RouteRepository routeRepository,
  @required LocationListener locationListener,
}) {
  StreamSubscription<Location> subscription;
  return here.LocationProvider.fromLambdas(
    lambda_start: () {
      if (!_simulate) {
        subscription =
            routeRepository.locationStream.listen((Location location) {
          locationListener.onLocationUpdated(location.toHereLocation());
        });
      }
    },
    lambda_stop: () => subscription?.cancel(),
    lambda_listener_get: () => locationListener,
    lambda_listener_set: (listener) => {},
  );
 }
```

**Solution**

I ended up extending my own class with `LocationProvider` instead of using the `fromLambdas` constructor from the LocationProvider class and now it's working. The callbacks are triggered.

Comment: Looks like you are using the features from Navigate Edition. Do you have access to the Navigate Edition SDK already? It is currently not public released in 4.3.3.0 yet.

Comment: yes, I also received credentials for that

Answer (score 1):

Feedback received from HERE SDK dev team :)

The locationListener is actually set by the SDK, and your implementation of LocationProviderImplementation is supposed to call the listener, otherwise no guidance will happen.

Please check the Android navigation example as a reference in [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/4.3.3.0/navigate/android/Navigation/app/src/main/java/com/here/navigation/LocationProviderImplementation.java), see line#28, and line#101.

Comment: Could you try remove "@required LocationListener locationListener,", and also provide an implementation for "lambda_listener_set: (listener) => {},", where you can set the provided listener to a variable that will be used to call onLocationUpdate()?

Comment: It seams that the fromLambdas doesn't work correctly or at least not as I expect it to work. Extending LocationProvider in my own class works.